# Set attribute to empty xml tag using jackson-dataformat-xml library

Tags: java, xml, jackson, xml-serialization

I have HashMap<String, Object> that is serialized into xml.
When Object is null

```
HashMap<String, Object> h1 = new HashMap<>();
h1.put("test", null);
System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(h1));
```

Jackson generates something like these

```
<HashMap>
   <test/>
</HashMap>
```

So I need somehow add attributes to this empty tag

```
<HashMap>
   <test attribute = "something"/>
</HashMap>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this ...

Instead of a `null` you need to use something like a thin wrapper around it, which will instruct `XmlMapper` to print this attribute information.

Here's a working test which solves the problem.

```
public class TestXml {
    
    class NullWrapper {
        @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
        private String attribute = "something";
    }

    @Test
    void test() throws JsonProcessingException {
        var mapper = new XmlMapper();
        var h1 = new HashMap<>();
        h1.put("test", new NullWrapper());
        System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(h1));
    }
}
```

Output is ...

```
<HashMap>
  <test attribute="something"/>
</HashMap>
```

Does this solve your problem ? Tell me in the comments.

Comment: Thank you a lot. That is just what I need

Comment: Any time, bro ;)

Comment: There is another question on the same topic. Maybe you know
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69929777/set-attributes-to-xml-tag-without-pojo-using-using-jackson-dataformat-xml-librar