# Set attributes to xml tag without POJO using jackson-dataformat-xml library

Tags: java, xml, jackson, xml-serialization

I use HashMap<String, Object> to serialize it into xml:

```
var mapper = new XmlMapper();
HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<>();
hm.put("header", "value");
System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(hm));
```

**Output**

```
<HashMap>
  <header>value</header>
</HashMap>
```

Problem is that I need to add unknown until runtime amount of attributes to header.

```
<HashMap>
  <header attr1= "text" attr2 = "another text" >value</header>
</HashMap>
```

Is there any workaround besides custom serializer?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
public class TestXml {
    
    class HeaderWrapper {
        @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
        private String attr1 = "text";

        @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
        private String attr2 = "another text";
    
        private String header = "value"
    }

    @Test
    void test() throws JsonProcessingException {
        var mapper = new XmlMapper();
        var h1 = new HashMap<>();
        h1.put("test", new NullWrapper());
        System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(h1));
    }
}
```

Comment: That`s the problem. I don't know the amount of attributes, name and value only the fact that there is List<Entry<String, String>> attributes

Comment: Dig in the official docs and check the list of annotation https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations